# Jsp Connection Error

Tags: apache, class, jsp, jdbc

When im trying to run this code to establish a connection ...... this error is coming

Im using Apache-tomcat-7.0.8

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

An error occurred at line: `1 in the jsp file: /test_conn.jsp`
Connection cannot be resolved to a type

```
1: <% Connection connection = null; try { // Load the JDBC driver String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; Class.forName(driverName);
2: 
3: // Create a connection to the database
4: String serverName = "URL";
```

Code I've tried:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*,java.text.*,java.util.*" %> 
<%@page import="java.util.*" %> 

<%
 Connection connection = null;
 out.println("Before try"); 
  try { 
      String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; 
      Class.forName(driverName); 
      out.println("Entered try"); 
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@:URL:port:sid"; 
      String username = "usr";
      String password = "pass"; 
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); 
      out.println("Successfully Connected"); 
   }catch (SQLException e) { 
      out.println("Not  Connected: "+ e.getMessage()); 
   } 
%>
```

Comment: Please include more code... like for getting driver connecton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use Servlet to write database code however you may import the java.sql package or use the Connection interface with fully qualified package name.

```
java.sql.Connection connection = null;
```

EDIT:

You need to copy the .jar (eg. for oracle 10g - ojdbc14.jar) into the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

In JSP you forgot to include

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
```

Though, this is not good practice. You should write Servlet and DAO  class to do this. JSP's are to write HTML.

Comment: After i used that code ,.... This error is Coming org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.test_005fconn_jsp
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:168)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:354)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)